# Find the value of $\Biggl(\Biggl(\tan^2\frac{7\pi}{24}-\tan^2\frac{\pi}{24}\Biggr):\Biggl(1-\tan^2\frac{7\pi}{24}\tan^2\frac{\pi}{24}\Biggr)\Biggr)^2$

Tags: trigonometry

This problem reminds me of the formula $\tan(x\pm y)=\frac{\tan(x)\pm \tan(y)}{1\mp \tan(x)\tan(y)}.$ But two minus signs in the problem interfere in applying the formula. I can't think of other ways. How to apply this formula?

Comment: There are lots of squares in the tan's. Looking at it as $((A-B):(1-CD))^2$, this means that each of $A$, $B$, $1$, and $CD$ are square terms. Squares and minus signs --> try factoring! :)

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle\;\frac{t_1^2 - t_2^2}{1-t_1^2t_2^2} = \left(\frac{t_1 - t_2}{1+t_1t_2}\right)\left(\frac{t_1+t_2}{1-t_1t_2}\right)$.

Comment: @achillehui Your hint is indeed the answer!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $A^{2}-B^{2} = (A-B)(A+B)$

Further hint:

> Use the hint to rewrite the expression as $\left(\frac{\tan{(7\pi/24)}-\tan{(\pi/24)}}{1+\tan{(7\pi/24)}\tan{(\pi/24)}}\cdot\frac{\tan{(7\pi/24)}+\tan{(\pi/24)}}{1-\tan{(7\pi/24)}\tan{(\pi/24)}}\right)^{2}$

Answer:

> The addition formula for $\tan$ then gives you the answer: $\left(\tan{\frac{6\pi}{24}}\tan{\frac{8\pi}{24}}\right)^{2} = \left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan{\frac{\pi}{3}}\right)^{2} = \left(1\cdot\sqrt{3}\right)^{2} = 3$

Answer (score 1):

It's $$\tan^2\frac{\pi}{4}\tan^2\frac{\pi}{3}=3$$